# Infimum of $C = \{\frac{1}{a} + b\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Working on some excercises on supremums and infimums of sets and am slightly confused over this one. Find: $$ \inf(C),\quad  C=\left\{\frac{1}{a} + b\ \middle\|\ a \in A , b\in B\right\}$$
We are also told that $\sup(A) <0$ and $\inf(B)$ exist.

It is obvious that the answer will be in terms of the infimums/ supremeums of $A$ and $B$, but in my head it should definitely depend on $\inf(A)$, but how do we even know this exists?

I understand that the answer will be of the form  $\ldots + \inf(B)$, just slightly confused about what happens in terms of $A$.

Comment: Which is smaller $-1/2$ or $-2$?  (Must notice the "${}<0$"...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sup A<0$, we have $\forall a\in A, a<0$. Then, 
\begin{align}
a'\geq a\implies \frac{1}{a'}&\leq \frac{1}{a}, \forall a,a'\in A\tag{1}\\
\end{align}

Since $\sup A\geq a$, $\forall a\in A$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sup A}\leq\frac{1}{a}, \forall a\in A\implies \frac{1}{\sup A}\leq\inf_{a'\in A}\frac{1}{a'}.\tag{2}$$

Let $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,\}$ be a sequence in $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\sup A$. From (1), we have
$$ \inf_{a'\in A}\frac{1}{a'}\leq\frac{1}{a_n}\implies \inf_{a'\in A}\frac{1}{a'}\leq\frac{1}{\sup A}.\tag{3}$$

Combining (2) and (3), we get $\inf_{a\in A} \frac{1}{a}= \frac{1}{\sup A}$. Therefore,
$$ \inf C = \inf_{a\in A,b\in B} \left\{\frac{1}{a}+b\right\} = \inf_{a\in A} \frac{1}{a}+\inf_{b\in B} b=  \frac{1}{\sup A}+\inf B.$$

Comment: Yeah I feel like I'm able to just "guess" a formula then check it holds under the $\epsilon$ definition of the infimum